# How to pass function as argument without executing it?

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

I have this function:

```
def a(one, two, the_argument_function):
    if one in two:
        return the_argument_function
```

my the_argument_function looks something like this:

```
def b(do_this, do_that):
    print "hi."
```

Both of the above are imported to a file "main_functions.py" for my ultimate code to look like this:

```
print function_from_main(package1.a, argument, package2.b(do_this, do_that)
```

The "if one in two" from "a"function works but "b"function still executes when being passed to "function_from_main" without waiting the check from "a" to see if it actually should execute.

What can I do?

Comment: You call `b` explicitly, how would it *not* execute?

Comment: @timgeb You understood my question perfectly.. Now then, how can I make it not execute?

Comment: don't call it..

Comment: @timgeb Perhaps I didn't write my questions correctly? I want to call it, but  only if "one in two" is satisfied, from package1.a , otherwise, my function_from_main doesn't know which function to actually call, somehow, I need to tell it, without actually executing it.

Comment: yet your are calling the function explicitly without waiting for the check when you pass its result to `function_from_main`.

Comment: pass the function, not its return value?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I simply don't know /how/ to write the specific code piece, since I'm not as good. Can you give me a snippet? All I'm trying to do is, again, say to main_func to not execute this function, rather keep its handle, then PROBABLY execute it later, if one in two is checked.

Comment: `function_from_main(..., package2.b, ...)` - now you have a reference to the function `b` inside `function_from_main` which may or may not call it.

Comment: I tried to see what you meant and gave it a bit of a hit-and miss. What I did was, to "a", I added "*args" and in my main, I did: function_from_main(..,..,  a, 'arg_to_a') which seemed to have solved it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`package2.b(do_this, do_that)` is a function call (a function name followed by parenthesis). Instead you should be passing only the function name `package2.b` the function `a`

You will also need to modify function `a` such that function be is called when the condition is satisfied

```
# function a definition 
def a(one, two, the_argument_function, argument_dict):
    if one in two:
        return the_argument_function(**argument_dict)

def b(do_this, do_that):
    print "hi."

# function call for a
a(one, two, b, {'do_this': some_value, 'do_that': some_other_value})
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if the solution worked. This will help other users to find the answer easily.